# numberOfRowsInSection not returning correct number of rows

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview

For the number of sections in my UITableView, I'm using the following function:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return _matchCenterArray.count;
}
```

This works properly, and shows the correct number of sections in the table. The `_matchCenterArray` that it refers to looks like this:

```
(
        {
        "Top 3" =         (
                        {
                "Image URL" = "http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mu05CM1bactFTAWZjesohNg/140.jpg";
                "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Nexus-7-Latest-Model-16GB-Wi-Fi-7in-Black-2nd-Generation-2013-/281443895415?pt=US_Tablets";
                Price = "170.0";
                Title = "Nexus 7 (Latest Model) 16GB, Wi-Fi, 7in - Black (2nd) Generation 2013";
            },
                        {
                "Image URL" = "http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mjkaCfDBdTQ6S-VTD0kFimA/140.jpg";
                "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Asus-Google-Nexus-7-2nd-Generation-Tablet-7-16GB-Android-4-3-/351173222631?pt=US_Tablets";
                Price = "165.59";
                Title = "Asus Google Nexus 7 2nd Generation Tablet 7\" 16GB Android 4.3 ";
            },
                        {
                "Image URL" = "http://thumbs4.ebaystatic.com/m/mjIENDWxrHTfcrO_Tmu4-zw/140.jpg";
                "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Google-Nexus-7-16GB-HD-K008-NEXUS7-ASUS-2B16-2nd-Gen-Tablet-Priority-Ship-/301315740555?pt=US_Tablets";
                Price = "164.99";
                Title = "Google Nexus 7 16GB HD K008 NEXUS7 ASUS-2B16 2nd Gen Tablet Priority Ship";
            },
                        {
                "Search Term" = "nexus 7 16gb";
            }
        );
    },
        {
        "Top 3" =         (
                        {
                "Image URL" = "http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/mbSjXw608gtlLhYC5GbrbOg/140.jpg";
                "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/rolex-datejust-/301318985642?pt=Wristwatches";
                Price = "400.0";
                Title = "rolex datejust";
            },
                        {
                "Image URL" = "http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/m/mx2eBCLXBEY30DXIIMrm_MQ/140.jpg";
                "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/VINTAGE-LADIES-ROLEX-STANDARD-17J-GOLD-FILLED-WATCH-WORKING-NICE-/111466728842?pt=Wristwatches";
                Price = "349.99";
                Title = "VINTAGE LADIES ROLEX STANDARD 17J GOLD FILLED WATCH WORKING NICE  ";
            },
                        {
                "Image URL" = "http://thumbs2.ebaystatic.com/m/mj7-GblU-4Al2X5q0sRvkfw/140.jpg";
                "Item URL" = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/Rolex-17000-Quartz-Datejust-BLACK-DIAL-5035-/271610085029?pt=Wristwatches";
                Price = "400.0";
                Title = "Rolex 17000 Quartz Datejust  BLACK DIAL 5035";
            },
                        {
                "Search Term" = rolex;
            }
        );
    }
)
```

As far as I can see, it is an array of **Top 3** arrays. In this case, there are two **Top 3** arrays, which results in two sections. In terms of the number of rows per section, I want it to be the number of dictionary objects in the Top 3 array.

In this case, they both seem to have 4 dictionaries within that array if I'm not mistaken. I've tried doing this with the function below, but it only shows one row per section:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSArray *currentSectionArray = _matchCenterArray[section];
    return currentSectionArray.count;

    return 3;
}
```

Comment: Have you try debugging it? Put a break point in the numberOfRowsInSection function and see what's the currentSectionArray holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your data source looks to me is that there are arrays of dictionaries, so each object associated with a section is a *dictionary*, not an array, and to get the array for this dictionary you need to access the object for the key, in this case "Top 3" to get the array for that section:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *currentSectionDictionary = _matchCenterArray[section];
    NSArray *top3ArrayForSection = currentSectionDictionary[@"Top 3"];
    return top3ArrayForSection.count;
}
```

Comment: It's right answer, or short version: return [_matchCenterArray[section][@"Top 3"] count];

Comment: Perhaps, but it's also *massively* easier to follow what is going on if you split the steps up as I did. Easier to step through when writing it, as well as if anyone else comes across the code later to be able to understand the data source setup as well. Shorter isn't always better :)

Answer (score 0):

_matchCenterArray[section] should be a dictionary, correct?  Could it be that you're assigning that NSDictionary to an NSArray variable?
maybe try

```
NSArray *currectSectionArray = [_matchCenterArray[section] allKeys];
return [currentSectionArray count];
```